# How to test throughput of application using rabbitmq?

Tags: testing, rabbitmq, performance-testing

I have application that uses rabbitmq to queue messages for other parts of ecosystem. I would like to do some performance testing and tuning, but just on my part (the program). So I guess I would like to somehow "mock" away the rabbitmq server, but without changes to my application.

Is there something like dummy rabbitmq server that just accepts all messages and throws them away immediately? Or can I configure actual rabbitmq in that way?

Comment: So, you typically don't "mock" remote tools/resources by connecting to a modified version of the remote. You usually write up a block of code that can mimic the interface and execute the desired behavior *in place of* the original tool your application needs. So, by that definition, it looks like what you really want is a misconfigured RabbitMQ, which I can't see would result in any valid test case.

Comment: Well I want to also benchmark my networking code. For that I assume I have to do actual network connection.

Answer (score 0):

I was using local docker image for the performance test. You can run it with the command:

```
docker run -d -p 8081:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

You can access management gui on `localhost:8081`, default username and password is guest/guest

After you are done running a performance test you can purge queue. You do that in Queues>your queue>Purge

PS: Port can be anything you want, just change 8081 in the docker command :)